# C#: implicitly convert double to float?

Tags: c#, double, implicit

I know implicit conversions from double to float are not allowed by default in C#, but is there any way I can enable such conversions? With a pragma of some sort? I'm not concerned with lack of precision (as my application doesn't require more than float precision anywhere), moreso just annoyed with having to always ensure I explicitly declare all decimal values as floats, or else I get compilation errors.

Comment: No, there isn’t. I wonder why there are so many numbers that are handled as floats and written explicitly in code that it’s a problem or a burden to add a single letter after, or they can’t be handled as doubles.

Comment: .NET has a specific [list of implicit numeric conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table) and all of them are for widening conversions... that is from types with smaller ranges to types with larger ranges.  Narrowing conversions like double to float require explicit conversions.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to avoid? There may be another way to handle what you trying to do, but it's a little unclear what you mean by "declare all decimals as floats".

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Since such a conversion could result in a precision loss, and the compiler has no way of determining whether it will or will not, you have to explicitly say that you're aware of the cast.

I'm unsure of what you mean by "explicitly declare decimals as floats", but in case you did not now, you can tell that a literal is a float by adding an `f` at the end

```
float a = 0.0;  // Wrong, implicit conversion.
float b = 0.0f; // OK. Can also be capital 'F'.
```

But if you're complaining about adding this one letter everywhere as a burden, then sorry, the answer is no, you can't work around that.

Answer (score -2):

No, there isn't any way to do it with implict conversion, but you may do it that way:

```
double a = 0.123456789123456789d;
float b = (float)a;
float c = Convert.ToSingle(a);
bool areBothSame = b == c;
Console.WriteLine("b == c: "areBothSame);
//Console Output:
//b == c: true
```

What Convert.ToSingle() does is that:

```
public static float ToSingle(double value)
{
    return (float)value;
}
```

So doesn't really maters what you prefer, it does the same job.

Comment: That's far from implicit conversion.

Comment: Well, there's no othe way